# combining consecutive matches and separating non-consecutive matches with from re findall

Tags: python-3.x, regex, python-re

I have a string of the format:

```
my_string = 'hello|foo world|foo how|bar are|bar you|bar today|foo'
```

I want to return a list where all consecutive words that are followed by foo are grouped together in the same string, but words with a '|bar' word in between are in separate strings. If I try a lookahead with repetition:

```
re.findall(r'(\w+(?=\|foo\b))+',my_string)
```

returns

```
['hello', 'world', 'today']
```

but I would like to return is

```
['hello world', 'today']
```

Because 'hello' and 'world' are not separated by a non-foo word.

In my real problem, the number of times sequences of words followed by 'foo' will appear in the string being searched is unknown, and 'bar' could be several different patterns.

I could solve it with a couple replaces, first replacing all non-foo patterns with a split indicator and splitting on that, then removing the foos and stripping spaces:

```
bars_removed = re.sub('(\w+\|(?!foo)[a-z]+ )+','split_string',my_string)
only_foo_words = [re.sub('\|foo','',x).strip() for x in bars_removed.split('split_string')]
```

which returns the desired result, but I feel like there's a way to do this using findall or maybe finditer that I'm missing.

Comment: You cannot "exclude" text in between other texts that are captured into the same group. Replace the lookahead with the consuming pattern and and then remove the `|foo` with a mere str.replace as the post-processing step. It is the only way. `[x.replace('|foo','') for x in re.findall(r'\w+\|foo(?:\s+\w+\|foo)*', my_string)]`. See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/skofUH/1).

Comment: Thank you! So I'm trying to understand your solution, could you explain what the `?:` non-capturing group does, is it just telling it not to assign subsequent consecutive occurrences of the match to a new group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot "exclude" text in between other texts that are captured into the same group.

You need to replace the lookahead with the consuming pattern, extract all consecutive matches, and  then remove the `|foo` with a mere `str.replace` method as the post-processing step.

```py
final_list = [x.replace('|foo','') for x in re.findall(r'\w+\|foo(?:\s+\w+\|foo)*', my_string)]
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/skofUH/1).

*Details*:

- `\w+` - one or more word chars
- `\|foo`  - a `|foo` string
- `(?:\s+\w+\|foo)*` - a non-capturing group matching zero or more sequences of

  - `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
  - `\w+\|foo` - one or more word chars and then a `|foo` string.